# Validar una dirección con JS utilizando pura algoritmia

Tags: javascript

```js
/ let direccion = document.getElementById('direccion').value;
// let arr = Array.from(direccion);
document.getElementById('boton').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
 let tipoVia = ['Calle/','Avenida/','Calleja/','Carretera/','Callejón/']
 let nombreVia = [] + ", ";
 let numVia = ['0, ','1, ','2, ','3, ','4, ','5, ','6, ','7, ','8, ','9, '];
 let restoVia = [] + ", ";
 let cpVia = [] + ", ";
 let poblacion = [] + ", ";
 let pais = [];
 let contc = 0;

 for(let i = 0; i < direccion.length; i++){
     direccion[0] = tipoVia;
     direccion[1] = nombreVia;
     direccion[2] = numVia;
     direccion[3] = restoVia;
     direccion[4] = cpVia;
     direccion[5] = poblacion;
     direccion[6] = pais;
    
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Ejercicios_JS/EjerciciosPOO/css/style.css">
    <title>Ejercicio</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="signupFrm">
     <form action="" class="form">
         <h1 class="title">Formulario</h1>
        
          <div class="inputContainer">
            <input type="text" id="direccion" class="input" placeholder="a" required>
            <label for="" class="label">Dirección</label>
          </div>
        
         
          <input type="submit" class="submitBtn" id="boton" value="Sign up">





    
    <script src="/Ejercicios_JS/EjerciciosPOO/js/ejercicio.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Mi problema es el siguiente no quiero utilizar EXPRESIONES REGULARES:
Validar una dirección que el usuario de en un solo input y el formato sea:
Tipo vía/ Nombre vía, Número, Resto de Datos (piso, portal...etc), CP, Población y País (separados por ,).Se trata de un campo obligatorio.

No tengo idea de cómo hacerlo por eso el javaScript es tan malo,no el lenguaje, sino mi código, por qué he pensado en diferentes putos de vista pero no consigo hacer nada.

Comment: "_por eso el javaScript es tan malo_" fuera de contexto totalmente. ¿En que _"lenguaje bueno"_ lo harías y no sería _"tan malo"_? Y sobretodo _¿Qué harías en "ese lenguaje bueno"_? Yo personalmente en todos usaría una expresión regular.

Comment: Lo se pero soy un junior y quiero aprender mejor las bases de la algoritmia de javaScript, por eso no quiero utilizar expresiones, se que es un royo y demasiado código que puede reducirse a menos de la mitad si utilizamos RegExp

Comment: "por eso el javaScript es tan malo" no me refiero al lenguaje me refiero a mi código

Comment: Pues entonces arma arreglos de los conjuntos de datos para cada fragmento, separas la dirección en componentes y comparas con tus arreglos a ver si cada una está ahí contenida. El problema está en que va a quedar mal "separado" para una dirección inválida, ahí tienes unas validaciones iniciales, etc. _Cada quien elige su veneno_. Trata de plantear preguntas concretas que no suenen a "no pude, completen ustedes" para que recibas buenas respuestas

Comment: Por otro lado, te recomiendo separar los campos en diferentes inputs, eso te facilitará mucho la validación y hará tu formulario más amigable. Un input para Nombre, un input para pais, uno para numero... etc. y los validas uno por uno. Así es cómo realmente se hace la mayor parte de las veces. Eso te permitirá validarlo mejor "sin expresiones regulares" y asegurarte de tener siempre direcciones consistentes, es decir, que todas las direcciones no luzcan diferentes.

Comment: @Alfabravo gracias lo intentare mejorar

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez muy amable por la idea, se que seria mas amigable y mucho mas fácil de hacer si realizase un input por cada dato, pero la idea es trabajar los ciclos así como los condicionales en grandes bloques pero como dijo Alfabravo  Cada quien elige su veneno.

Comment: El problema que tenes con tu planteo, es como diferencias por ejemplo que datos son los que llamas restovia con el siguiente.. y asi todos.. que pasa si la calle tiene varios nombres? las direcciones no es algo que se pueda manejar de esta forma....